# Can i get the name of an java voice chat application which connect using IP?

Tags: java, sockets, window, ip, desktop

Is there any window desktop application is available for voice chat based on pure IP connection?
it should not use any server?
Based on ip it should connect..

Comment: You will require a server at some point , Client to Server relationship, you could do one Client to Client but how should the client know to `listen` for incoming connections unless it was a server too. The SO forum is not there to find software but to assist with specific coding stumbling blocks

Comment: Thank u for your reply..Ok lets think i am having two machines.machine1 will act as server.i need to connect machine2 with the machine1 using the machine1 ip address.i need a applicaion or java code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a java applet that runs through the web interface: http://www.smaxe.com/applet.jsf?id=rtmp-audio-chat

Though I'm assuming you want some source code so here is a link (planetsourcecode) for just that: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4644&lngWId=2